# jsf open dialog on success

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a button in my JSF page that saves a project.

```
<p:commandButton id="saveB" actionListener="#{projectsController.create}" value="Projeyi Kaydet" icon="ui-icon-check"  onsuccess="infDialog.show()" onerror="infDialog.hide()"/>
```

As I click it saves the project and opens the dialog and says it is saved. Here is my dialog:

```
<p:dialog id="msgDialog" header="Bilgi" widgetVar="infDialog" resizable="true" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode" appendToBody="true" modal="true" closable="false">
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="10" style="margin:0 auto;">  
            <f:facet name="header">
                <center>
                    <h:outputText value="Proje kaydedildi." />
                </center>
            </f:facet>

            <h:outputText value="Projeye döküman eklemek için aşağıdaki paneli kullanabilirsiniz." />


            <f:facet name="footer">
                <center>
                    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">  

                        <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploader.handleFileUpload}"  
                                      mode="advanced"  
                                      update="messages"  
                                      auto="false"  
                                      sizeLimit="100000000"  
                                      multiple="true"
                                      allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|avi|mpeg|mp4)$/"/>  

                        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>  

                    </h:form>
                </center>
            </f:facet>
            <br />
            <br />
            <center>
                <p:commandButton value="Proje Eklemeyi Tamamla" onclick="window.location.replace(window.location.href);"/>
            </center>

        </h:panelGrid>  
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

My problem here is when I don't fill any field it still shows up and says project is created instead of saying you to check the form again.

How can I achieve this? Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated since 1998. Keep your HTML knowledge up to date.

Answer (score 3):

First your structure is not considered correct because you have nested `<form>` tags. That's not correct in HTML, and so it is not correct in JSF.

Second `onerror` callback doesn't have anything with form validation, but with errors in AJAX request. You should change `onsuccess` and `onerror` and use something like this:

```
oncomplete="handleSave(xhr, status, args)"
```

and define JavaScript function like this:

```
if (args.validationFailed) {
    infDialog.hide()
} else {
    infDialog.show()
}
```

`validationFailed` is ajax callback parameter which is implicitly set by Primefaces to true if there was some validation errors. You also should add `required="true"` attribute to `p:fileUpload` tag if it is required.